# Accessing FAST ESP admin services (Dictionary and Deployment manager) from .net

Tags: .net, performance, fast-esp

I am looking for a way to access the FAST ESP Admin services from within my .net code. The situation is, we have dictionaries deployed in FAST for autocomplete, spellcheck etc. and we are looking to build an application layer to maintain and manipulate these dictionaries.

From reading the FAST ESP Application Integration Guide, there seems to be an ESP Admin services layer that applications can connect to do operations such as this. I am specifically looking to be able to connect to the Dictionary service and Deployment manager service.

I tried consuming the Dictionary webservice at baseport+3089/adminserver/dictionaryService.jws and the contracts of this service seem very sketchy at best with input parameters like in0, in1 - not sure what these mean?

Could somebody please provide any guidance or pointers into how this could be done?